# Can I use grid everywhere I want?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can I use grid system like this?

I was trying to make those list time side by side but one element goes down.

Margin won't work but only `position: relatives` works but it does not make it responsive. So I used grid system.

Is it bad practice?

```
<ul class="list-inline col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
    <li class="col-md-3"> 
        <select class="form-control">
            <option> Voice over category </option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3"> 
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="zip" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Find Coaches </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, the grid isn't meant to be used everywhere. Read the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Looks like this is your [2nd question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068571/what-is-wrong-with-my-code) w/o any effort to ready the docs.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's wrong. Cols have to be inside a row. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

If you want to have an inline form there's a class for that:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

If you still want to use cols, then:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```